# Why file mapping in Hibernate in my eclipse always set defaut 2.0

Tags: java, hibernate

I have problem when I have created file mapping in Hibernate Java. File mapping default is set to 2.0, and I change it to 3.0. So I have many errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-2.0.dtd" >
```

How to set default to 3.0 in file mapping in Hibernate? I use Eclipse Juno.
Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Are you using Hibernate tools?

Comment: Yes. I have choose new file --> Hibernate Mapping file in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `preferences -> XML -> XML Catalog` are stored all `xml file templates`. Add the `3.0 version` and remove the `2.0`. Then create a mapping.